# Opening or creating a project on timeXtender

Tags: data-warehouse, business-intelligence, agile

I am very new to timextender and still in early learning stages (self study) i have installed both the client and server both of which are 2012.
I am unable to create a project in timextender 2012, i have a trial license which is still valid. 
Pretty much everything in the app is disabled, except the open project button yet when i press the button all it does is send an error messagebox with the text "no license for feature project"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates that the license you are using is for a later version of TX DWA. You can download the latest version from the TimeXtender support-site: http://support.timextender.com and you can request a new trial from the application or use your partner license!

Rgds,

Thomas Duun
CTO, TimeXtender